# Positioning \tstar.... on a page

Tags: tikz-pgf, nodes

Horizontal positioning of `\tstar` can be done with `\hspace*{}`, but attempts at vertical positioning with either `\vspace{}` or writing `\node (x) at (somex,somey) {\tstar{}{}{}{}}` fails.

How can I adjust the vertical placement of \tstar?

## Minimal example:

```
\documentclass[landscape,12pt]{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.geometric}

\usepackage{pstricks}
\usepackage{fix-cm}

\usepackage{geometry}
\geometry{
  top=0.5in,            
  inner=0.5in,
  outer=0.5in,
  bottom=0.5in,
  headheight=3ex,       
  headsep=2ex,          
}

\newcommand\score[2]{
\pgfmathsetmacro\pgfxa{#1+1}
\tikzstyle{scorestars}=[star, star points=5, star point ratio=2.25, draw,inner sep=0.15em,anchor=outer point 3]
\begin{tikzpicture}[baseline]
  \foreach \i in {1,...,#2} {
    \pgfmathparse{(\i<=#1?"yellow":"gray")}
    \edef\starcolor{\pgfmathresult}
    \draw (\i*1em,0) node[name=star\i,scorestars,fill=\starcolor]  {};
   }
   \pgfmathparse{(#1>int(#1)?int(#1+1):0}
   \let\partstar=\pgfmathresult
   \ifnum\partstar>0
     \pgfmathsetmacro\starpart{#1-(int(#1))}
     \path [clip] ($(star\partstar.outer point 3)!(star\partstar.outer point 2)!(star\partstar.outer point 4)$) rectangle
    ($(star\partstar.outer point 2 |- star\partstar.outer point 1)!\starpart!(star\partstar.outer point 1 -| star\partstar.outer point 5)$);
     \fill (\partstar*1em,0) node[scorestars,fill=yellow]  {};
   \fi

,\end{tikzpicture}
}

\newcommand{\tstar}[5]{% inner radius, outer radius, tips, rot angle, options
\pgfmathsetmacro{\starangle}{360/#3}
\draw[#5] (#4:#1)
\foreach \x in {1,...,#3}
{ -- (#4+\x*\starangle-\starangle/2:#2) -- (#4+\x*\starangle:#1)
}
-- cycle;
}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}

%%% \node (st) at (x,y) {\tstar{1}{3}{27}{17}{fill=red}}; fails.

\tstar{1}{3}{27}{17}{fill=red};

\node (x) at (10,1) {{ \fontsize{100}{120}\selectfont\bf Stuff}};

\end{tikzpicture}


\end{document}
```

Comment: Editing it thrice makes my rep increase 6 points. Lucky!

Comment: The problem is: where do you want to place it?

Comment: Not sure yet! I'd like to be able to adjust the vertical positioning of \tstar....

Answer (score 1):

You can add `xshift` and `yshift` to the fifth argument of `\tstar`, e.g.

```
\tstar{1}{3}{27}{17}{fill=red,xshift=2cm,yshift=-5cm};
```

On an unrelated note, use `\bfseries` not `\bf`, the latter is deprecated (see [Does it matter if I use `\textit` or `\it`, `\bfseries` or `\bf`, etc.](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/516)).

[image]

```
\documentclass[landscape,12pt]{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.geometric}

\usepackage{pstricks}
\usepackage{fix-cm}

\usepackage{geometry}
\geometry{
  top=0.5in,            
  inner=0.5in,
  outer=0.5in,
  bottom=0.5in,
  headheight=3ex,       
  headsep=2ex,          
}

\newcommand\score[2]{
\pgfmathsetmacro\pgfxa{#1+1}
\tikzstyle{scorestars}=[star, star points=5, star point ratio=2.25, draw,inner sep=0.15em,anchor=outer point 3]
\begin{tikzpicture}[baseline]
  \foreach \i in {1,...,#2} {
    \pgfmathparse{(\i<=#1?"yellow":"gray")}
    \edef\starcolor{\pgfmathresult}
    \draw (\i*1em,0) node[name=star\i,scorestars,fill=\starcolor]  {};
   }
   \pgfmathparse{(#1>int(#1)?int(#1+1):0}
   \let\partstar=\pgfmathresult
   \ifnum\partstar>0
     \pgfmathsetmacro\starpart{#1-(int(#1))}
     \path [clip] ($(star\partstar.outer point 3)!(star\partstar.outer point 2)!(star\partstar.outer point 4)$) rectangle
    ($(star\partstar.outer point 2 |- star\partstar.outer point 1)!\starpart!(star\partstar.outer point 1 -| star\partstar.outer point 5)$);
     \fill (\partstar*1em,0) node[scorestars,fill=yellow]  {};
   \fi

,\end{tikzpicture}
}

\newcommand{\tstar}[5]{% inner radius, outer radius, tips, rot angle, options
\pgfmathsetmacro{\starangle}{360/#3}
\draw[#5] (#4:#1)
\foreach \x in {1,...,#3}
{ -- (#4+\x*\starangle-\starangle/2:#2) -- (#4+\x*\starangle:#1)
}
-- cycle;
}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}

%%% \node (st) at (x,y) {\tstar{1}{3}{27}{17}{fill=red}}; fails.

\tstar{1}{3}{27}{17}{fill=red};
\tstar{1}{3}{27}{17}{fill=red,xshift=2cm,yshift=-5cm};

\node (x) at (10,1) {{ \fontsize{100}{120}\selectfont\bfseries Stuff}};

\end{tikzpicture}


\end{document}
```

Comment: @user39678 Glad it helped. If you end up using this solution, you might consider accepting my answer by clicking the checkmark to the left (same for Jake's answer to your other question). That marks the question as solved, and awards some points to both yourself and me.